# SQL Error trying to get a BETWEEN in a DateTime2 Column

Tags: sql

I am trying to filter a SQL database using `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM RegistroCaja 
WHERE Fecha BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime2, '15/12/2021 08:54:33')
                AND CONVERT(datetime2, '17/12/2021 08:54:34')
```

But I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The `Fecha` column is of type `DateTime2`, if someone can help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dates are not formatted for valid datetime2 parsing:

[image]

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 for more information.  But switch the day with the month and you should be able to do the conversion.

Comment: Thanks that actually worked, is there any chance i could possibly use the CONVERT function to do the actual change by itself?

Comment: @devCcori select convert( datetime2, '15/12/2021 08:54:33', 103)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely format problem, try to use:

```
SELECT * 
    From RegistroCaja 
    WHERE Fecha BETWEEN
        CONVERT(datetime2 , '2021-12-15 08:54:33')
        and CONVERT(datetime2, '2021-12-17 08:54:34')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the style as the third argument to CONVERT function.

```
SELECT * 
    From RegistroCaja 
    WHERE Fecha BETWEEN
        CONVERT(datetime2 , '15/12/2021 08:54:33', 131)
        and CONVERT(datetime2, '17/12/2021 08:54:34', 131)
```

Comment: using 131 doesn't return me any result meanwhile using 103 returns the results.